# How to update a record saved in mongodb using nodejs and mongo client?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

**Saved date in mongodb**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a8a95c431789513bc542334")
        "projectName" : "MMMMM",
        "testCases" : [ 
            {
                "groupName" : "Data Validation Bucket 19"
            },
            {
                "groupName" : "Test"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**JSON request**

```
{
    "_id" : "5a8a95c431789513bc542334",
    "updateData" : {
        "projectName": "MMMMM",
        "testCases": [
          {
            "groupName": "Data Validation Bucket 19"
          },
          {
            "groupName": "Data Validation Bucket 123"
          }
         ]  
    }
}
```

**Nodejs code**

```
module.exports.update = function (data, callback) {
    var connection = myDB.get();
    var id = data._id;
    var dataToUpdate = data.updateData;

    var reponse = {
        'status' : ''
    }

    if(id) {
        console.log(id);
        console.log(dataToUpdate);
        connection.collection('REPORTS').update({_id : id}, {$set:dataToUpdate}, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reponse.status = constantsUtils.ERROR;
                callback(reponse);
            } else {
                reponse.status = constantsUtils.UPDATE_SUCCESS;
                callback(reponse);                
            }
        });
    } else {
        reponse.status = constantsUtils.INVALID_INPUT;
        callback(reponse);
    }
};
```

i am trying to update a record saved in mongodb using nodejs and mongoclint.
i am using nodejs restful webservice and request is served successfully but not able to update the record present in moongodb.

i am trying to update **projectName** and **testCases[1].groupName**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)** operator for the array update since it allows you to add a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)** does nothing to that array. For the other non-array field, **`$set`** will suffice.

Consider refactoring your method to

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb'); 
const safeObjectId = s => ObjectId.isValid(s) ? new ObjectId(s) : null;

module.exports.update = function (data, callback) {
    let collection = myDB.get().collection('REPORTS'),
        query = {},
        update = {},
        id = data._id,
        dataToUpdate = data.updateData,
        response = { 'status' : '' };

    const handleError = err => {
        console.error(err);
        reponse.status = constantsUtils.ERROR;
        callback(reponse);
    }

    const handleSuccess = res => {
        console.log(res);
        reponse.status = constantsUtils.UPDATE_SUCCESS;
        callback(reponse);
    }

    const handleInvalidInput = () => {
        reponse.status = constantsUtils.UPDATE_SUCCESS;
        callback(reponse);
    }       

    if ( id ) {
        query['_id'] = { '_id': safeObjectId(id) };
        update['$set'] = { 'projectName': dataToUpdate.projectName };

        if( Object.prototype.toString.call( dataToUpdate.testCases ) === '[object Array]' ) {
            update['$addToSet'] = { 'testCases': { '$each': dataToUpdate.testCases  } };
        }

        collection.findOneAndUpdate(
            query, 
            update, 
            { returnOriginal: false }
        ).then(handleSuccess, handleError);

    } else {
        handleInvalidInput();
    }
};
```

Comment: i am getting `safeObjectId is not defined` error. so it is a inbuilt method or need to create that ?

Comment: @SangramBadi It's already defined right at the top of the code snippet just before the `module.exports`. You could move it in the function or create a helper file with these helper methods since you will need the function to cast string `_id`s to `ObjectId`s